# How To Implement Unity 'XR Simple Interactable' Correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

**Documentation for** [Simple Interactable](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit@0.9/api/UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit.XRSimpleInteractable.html)

**Documentation for** [Grab Interactable](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit@0.0/api/UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit.XRGrabInteractable.html)

[image: XR Grab Interactable Example]

I've been developing an application for the Oculus Quest in Unity. Due to the Quest's limited hardware, I am trying to minimize the processing required in my application. Fr obvious reasons, this makes `XRSimpleInteractable` very appealing to attach to a collider where all I want to do is action the player's controller is selecting the object, rather than `XRGrabInteractable` which also computes a rigid-body that can be rotated and repositioned.

However, whenever  `SimpleInteractable` is attached to a `GameObject`, placing the `GameObject`s collision box into the `colliders` array of the `XRSimpleInteractable` and moving the controller into the collision box does not activate the previosuly set `onSelectEntered` script.

With `XRGrabInteractable`s attached `onSelectEntered` script however, it does, using the same script reference.

Can someone explain how to correctly use `XRSimpleInteractable` ?

Comment: If you want to edit your existing question, just do so. No need to post a new one.

Comment: @gunr2171 I was under the impression that was closed

Comment: The one I linked? Nope, still open. You can edit the post even if it's closed, and it will go into a review queue to be reopened.

Comment: @gunr2171 , cool, have edited it as such :)

Comment: Too bad this was closed, the linked question goes to a Page Not Found.